# python subprocess module, works with communicate() not with process.stdin.write()

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

Im creating a mp3 player from python in ubuntu with omxplayer installed.

Im using a tkinter frame to have a play/pause button. When the python script is ran it displays a play button, once the play button is hit the mp3 will begin, and the button text changes to pause. The user can then click the pause button, the mp3 pauses and the button text changes. The cycle continues etc. As i am using the keybindings for omxplayer, I am using the subprocess module to write to the command line.

The code I have is: https://codedump.io/share/8Sw4UfNIg4ZQ/1/mp3-player

The important function is `musicPlay`:

```
def musicPlay():
    global player, playing

    if musicPlayButton["text"] == "Play": #If not paused
        musicPlayButton["text"] = "Pause"

        if playing == False: #If player isn't loaded
            songString = library + "/" + libraryList[libraryIndex]
            player = subprocess.Popen(["omxplayer","-o","local",songString],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            playing = True

        elif playing == True: #If player is loaded
            player.communicate(input=(bytes('q',"UTF-8")))

    elif musicPlayButton["text"] == "Pause":
        musicPlayButton["text"] = "Play"
        player.communicate(input=(bytes('q',"UTF-8")))
```

This correctly starts the mp3 and pauses the mp3 for the first time.

Reading through the documentation on the `subprocess` module, it states that the `communicate` method closes the stdin pipe. So from other questions on stack overflow, it was suggested to replace `communicate` with `stdin.write`.

When I do this the mp3 starts but will not pause, and seems to not complete the write to stdin.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Your problem right here `subprocess.Popen(["omxplayer","-o","local",songString],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` so `omxplayer` allow pause on a shell ? No, try yourself in a terminal !